# Confluent MSSQL CDC Connector not fetching changes

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka-connect, cdc

If anyone had played with Confluent MSSQL CDC Connector (https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-cdc-mssql/index.html)
I tried setting up this connector, downloading the jar and setting up config files as mentioned in docs. Running it is actually not throwing any error but it NOT able to fetch any changes from the SQL Server. Below is my config:

```
{
"name" : "mssql_cdc_test",
"connector.class" : "io.confluent.connect.cdc.mssql.MsSqlSourceConnector",
"tasks.max" : "1",
"initial.database" : "DBASandbox",
"username" : "xxx",
"password" : "xxx",
"server.name" : "rptdevdb01111.homeaway.live",
"server.port" : "1433",
"change.tracking.tables" : "dbo.emp"
}
```

This is the message I am getting in the logs (at INFO level) :

```
INFO Source task WorkerSourceTask{id=mssql_cdc_test-0} finished initialization and start (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:143)
```

Strange is even if I change the server.name to some junk value, it doesn’t bother and no errors. So, probably its NOT even trying to hit my sql server.

I did also enable change tracking on Database as well specified Table:

```
ALTER DATABASE DBASandbox  
SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON  
(CHANGE_RETENTION = 2 DAYS, AUTO_CLEANUP = ON)

ALTER DATABASE DBASandbox  
SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON

ALTER TABLE dbo.emp  
ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING  
WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = ON)
```

Not sure whats wrong and how to debug it further. Any clue or insight will be helpful.

Comment: I am having the same issue. DId you get any solution for it ?